# Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet

my Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize my Ethernet connection.the same connection in windows works fine. But it gets connected to Wi-fi.

Comment: What do you mean , it doesnt even recognize your ethernet connection?
Do a `ifconfig` and see if there is any connection like `eth0` or `enp2s0`.
If not you have install required ethernet drivers. And afterall we need more info about the hardware and preferebly the screenshots to work upon the problem.Please update the question. Cheers

Comment: Yes i have eth0. And i just found out that it gets connected to my Ethernet in library. I think there is some problem with my port. But Windows could connect to don't know why Ubuntu could not.

Comment: And also it was showing  me Network Service discovery disabled later on to  which i typed this command sudo -i
 gedit /etc/default/avahi-daemon and did this AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of network-manager. You can re-install network manager and it would the reset it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

Restart your PC , and check out your Ethernet connection.

Comment: Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package network
E: Unable to locate package manager
this is what it shows. And i just found out that it is recognizing ethernet in my library but nt room i think the problem is with room port